# Binding DependencyProperty to DependencyProperty only working in one direction

Tags: wpf, binding

I'm using WPF with C#.
I have a custom control which contains a TextBox. The custom control has a dependencyproperty FilterText. A CurrentText property of my ViewModel is binded to the FilterText property of my control.

Goal is that when the Text-property of the TextBox changes, this updates the CurrentText property of my ViewModel.

Problem: Updating the Text of the TextBox doesn't update the FilterText DP of my control. However, changing the FilterText property does update the Text of the TextBox.

The custom usercontrol:

```
<UserControl x:Name="generalQuickSearch" (..)>
(..)
     <TextBox Text="{Binding FilterText, ElementName=generalQuickSearch, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
(..)
</UserControl>
```

The Dependency Property in codebehind of the usercontrol:

```
 public static readonly DependencyProperty FilterTextProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("FilterText", typeof(string), typeof(GeneralQuickSearch));
```

In my view, using the custom control:

```
<controls:GeneralQuickSearch FilterText="{Binding CurrentText, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
```

Using Snoop, when I enter text in the textbox:

[image: Text property of the TextBox]

FilterText property on my generalQuickSearch control:

[image: FilterText property on GeneralQuickSearch control]

I don't see why this isn't working. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem and solution: The Text property of TextBox is by default only updated at LostFocus. This can be changed by adding this to the binding:

```
UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged
```

Source: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.binding.updatesourcetrigger%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

> The default is Default, which returns the default UpdateSourceTrigger value of the target dependency property. However, the default value for most dependency properties is PropertyChanged, while the Text property has a default value of LostFocus.